# How to bind a property from code-behind while the rest are bound to DataContext?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

My goal is to bind an element property in XAML to a property of the code behind class, while the DataContext still is a ViewModel.

The reason is, that I have some only UI-cosmetic properties in XAML which are not controlled by the ViewModel but by the code behind.

So essentially I search something like that:

```
<Element 
    Attribute = "{Binding ThatOneCodeBehind.WhateverProperty}"
    OtherAttribute1 = "{Binding StillDataContextSomething}" 
    OtherAttribute2 = "{Binding StillDataContextSomething}"
/>
```

What is the correct binding Syntax for `Attribute="{Binding ThatOneCodeBehind:WhateverProperty}"`?

Comment: Is 'ThatOneCodeBehind.WhateverProperty' a DependencyProperty of the main control that contains your 'Element' control?

Comment: Give that element a name and you have access to it from Code. eg: `<Element x:Name="Test" ...` from code: T`est.Attribute = WhateverYouWant`

Comment: Assuming the "code behind" you are referring to is that of a Window, make sure WhateverProperty is a public property in the window class, and bind like `{Binding WhateverProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code behind is in some UIElement, let say `Window`. So give your element with code behind name and do bind to it. Of course property `CodeBehindProperty` should be defined there.

```
<Window x:Name="_this">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CodeBehindProperty, ElementName=_this}"/>
</Window>
```

Another way is to find the ancestor with defined type:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CodeBehindProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Perfekt - this was exactly what I've searched for but didn't worked out properly. Thank you very much! And thanks also to the other comment distributors.